# How to change css class name from camel to kebab case?

Tags: css, styles, stylelint

I am using stylelint to lint a legacy project. The challenge here is that some of the CSS classes are written in Camel Case by earlier developers. And now I need to convert them to Kebab Case.

Is there a solution to convert css class case ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would use [a css parser](https://github.com/reworkcss/css) to make sure you are only messing with class names (or other selectors) and not the actual css properties. But assuming it is a simple css file, search and replace might do the trick.

```js
var css = `
.helloWorld, .hello-world {
  background-color: red;
}

.someThing::before {
  background: red;
}
`

const kebabize = (str) => str.replace(/[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z]/g, ($, ofs) => (ofs ? "-" : "") + $.toLowerCase())

css = css.replace(/\b(\S+)\b/ig, function(a, b) {
  return (kebabize(b))
});

console.log(css)
```